# Factorising an integer recursively and some questions about functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, primes, prime-factoring, type-signature

I've just started to learn Haskell after coming from Python, and I've got a couple of questions about functions. I've written the following code:

```
--generating prime list
primes = sieve [2..]
sieve (p:ps) = p : sieve [x | x <- ps, mod x p /= 0]

--factorising function
--takes an input of a number and a list of primes and outputs a list of its prime factors
factorise (n,ps)
    | mod n head ps /= 0    = div n head ps : factorise (div n head ps, ps)
    | otherwise             = factorise (n,tail ps)
```

Firstly, when I try to compile, I get an error relating to `n`, saying I `cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a] -> a`, why is this?

Secondly, while I understand the logic behind creating an infinite list, why do you not have to explicitly state the types of the function `sieve`, are the types implied? Would I have to, for the `factorise` function?

Lastly, is there a more concise way of writing the above algorithm (which I understand is horribly efficient)?

Comment: Hint: `mod n head ps` needs some brackets... Furthermore `ps` can be empty.

Comment: `why do you not have to explicitly state the types of the function sieve, are the types implied?` indeed, Haskell has type inference so it's relatively rare to need type signatures for code to compile. However, it's still very strongly encouraged to include type signatures for top level definitions like these. They document your code better, and generally lead to more understandable error messages.

Comment: I agree with Robin, but want to add that including explicit type declarations can also lead the compiler to catch errors it would otherwise miss entirely.

Comment: it is also common for newbies to add incorrect type signatures which prevent compiler from compiling a code for which it would infer the correct type on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding some parentheses here and there fixes the problem:

```
factorise (n, ps)
    | mod n (head ps) /= 0  = div n (head ps) : factorise (div n (head ps), ps)
    | otherwise             = factorise (n, tail ps)
```

Parentheses are used for grouping in Haskell. `mod n (head ps)` is an application of `mod` to two arguments, `n` and `head ps`; without the parens `mod n head ps` is an application of `mod` to three arguments, `n`, `head` and ps`, and this just doesn't typecheck.

Indeed after the error is fixed all the types are successfully inferred, as

```
primes :: Integral a => [a]
sieve   :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]
factorise :: Integral a => (a, [a]) -> [a]
```

Now you can specialize them if you so wish, as

```
primes :: [Integer]
sieve   :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
factorise :: (a ~ Integer) => (a, [a]) -> [a]
```

(the latter way of writing the type for `factorise` needs the `GADTs` extension enabled).

For your original code with the type signature included,

```
factorise :: Integral a => (a, [a]) -> [a]
factorise (n,ps)
    | mod n head ps /= 0    = div n head ps : factorise (div n head ps, ps)
    | otherwise             = factorise (n,tail ps)
```

the error message is essentially the same. It says "Could not deduce `(a ~ ([a] -> a))`" but still shows that as far as the compiler can see, the `a` type must also be `[a] -> a` at the same time (so it must also be `a ~ [a] -> ([a] -> a)`, `a ~ [[a] -> a] -> ([a] -> ([a] -> a))`, etc. etc. (hence the "infinite" type reference in the first error message)).

If that were indeed the type you intended it could be made legal by naming it and making it *explicitly* recursive, as

```
data T a = MkT ([T a] -> T a)
```

This *is* allowed. Haskell is perfectly capable of having recursive types. After all,  simple *list* type is recursive, as if defined by

```
data [] a = [] | a : ([] a)
data L a = Nil | Cons a (L a)
```

I'll leave addressing the efficiency issues in `factorise` for later. With `sieve` though it is pretty straightforward: its *main* problem is that it only produces one prime at a time, whereas it is perfectly capable of producing more, much more than that, at each one step.

Can you find a way how?

---

Your `factorise` function is a perfectly fine rendering of the simple trial division factorization algorithm (except for few simple errors). One way to improve conciseness (and subsequently correctness!)   is to introduce interim variables with `let` (or, better, `where`, to be able to use them in guards as well), as in

```
factorise (n, ps)
  | mod n f /= 0  =                        -- is the test correct?
                    v : factorise (v, ps)  -- is it really v : ... ?
  | otherwise     = factorise (n, tail ps)
     where
       f = head ps 
       v = div n f
```

... except it never stops! You must include an additional test to stop producing the list of prime factors.

Can you find a way how? :)

Comment: It works now! Thanks for the explanation of the error and clearing up my understanding of types!

Answer (score 1):

My solution (I forgot to give a base case for the recursion as well as some other corrections):

```
--generating prime list
primes :: Integral a => [a]
primes = sieve [2..]

sieve   :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]
sieve (p:ps) = p : sieve [x | x <- ps, mod x p /= 0]

--factorising function
--takes an input of a number and a list of primes and outputs a list of its prime factors
factorise :: Integral a => (a, [a]) -> [a]
factorise (n, ps)
    |   n == 1          = []
    |   mod n f == 0    = f : factorise (v, ps)
    |   otherwise       = factorise (n, tail ps)
    where
        f = head ps
        v = div n f
```

Comment: two algorithmic performance problems here, both related to `sqrt` and its inverse. :) one in `sieve`, the other in `factorise`. hint: `factorise (47, 2:3:5:7:undefined)` should not cause an error. second hint: `take 1000 (sieve [2..])` should only create a chain of 24 nested invocations of `sieve`, not 999; `take 10000 ...` - just 66, not 9999;  `take 1000000 ...` - just 546, not 999999.